# rails 4 data iteration from activerecord search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to iterate over a hash returned from an active record search.

the data comes back {[k, v] => v, [k,v] => v, etc.} and I need to place that data in 3 separate columns of a table.

what I have so far in a helper is

```
data = {}
      connector = 0
      us_cords = 0
      eu_cords = 0
      molex_connector = 0

      chart_data_two.each do |key, value|
        data[key[0]] ||= Hash.new
        data[key[0]][key[1]] = value
      end
    return data
```

This gives me the k out of the k,v pair above and then a hash with "v" => v from above.

[image: Table Output]

so I am having a hard time wrapping my head around iterating over the data hash and putting it into the view table in each column.

The view has @table_data_two  = chart_qty_monthly_data(@chart_data_two) and then @table_data_two.each do |k,v| for generating each row/column.

Comment: Could you post some sample data?  Within `[k, v] => v`, does v == v?

Comment: It's in the picture; but here is what is first coming in as chart_data_two:

`{["Connector", "1"]=>4481, ["Connector", "10"]=>722, ["Connector", "2"]=>132, ["Connector", "3"]=>1467, ["Connector", "4"]=>3438, ["Connector", "5"]=>1627, ["Connector", "6"]=>508, ["EU Cords", "1"]=>218, ["EU Cords", "2"]=>100, ["US Cords", "1"]=>292, ["US Cords", "2"]=>256}`

this is coming in as {Model, Month} => Sum(Quantity) from an active records search.

There are 4 model types, up to 12 months, and then the corresponding SUM(Quantity) for each model type per month.

Comment: also what I need to do with the chart_data_two is split the data into 3 columns Month, Model, SUM(Quantity).  Eventually it might be nice to do only one merged cell for month with 4 cells for model and then the quantities; one thing at a time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up doing it a bit different:

```
data = {}

#initialize hash keys in the order you want them to end up in
(1..12).each do |month|
  data[month] = {"Connector" => 0, "US Cords" => 0, "EU Cords" => 0}
end

chart_data_two.each do |key, value|
#key[1] is month. we're referencing the keys we initialized above
#key[2] is model. we're adding a new key to the nested hash we initialized above
  #logger.info "#{key[0]}, #{key[1]}, #{value}"
  data[key[1].to_i][key[0]] = value
  #logger.info "%%%%%%%% inside iterator #{data}"
end
#logger.info "$$$$$ passing #{data} into chart"
return data
```

end

I got help with figuring that out, but I wanted to post it here.

Answer (score 1):

> Eventually it might be nice to do only one merged cell for month with 4 cells for model and then the quantities

Here's one way to build that:

```
data = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {} }

chart_data_two.each do |key, value|
  model_quantity = { key[0] => value }
  data[key[1]].merge!(model_quantity)
end
```

If you want it to be in order by month, you can change the keys to integers and sort it:

```
data = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {} }

chart_data_two.each do |key, value|
  model_quantity = { key[0] => value }
  data[key[1].to_i].merge!(model_quantity)
end

sorted_data = data.sort.to_h
```

It's not perfect, so I'll look it over again and see what could be improved, but it will at least get you started, assuming I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong when I create the table, your code moves what is displayed first around, but still only gives me two columns of data.
making tables in comments is hard, but basically month is populating month, but a hash is in the model column and quantity is blank.  I need to break everything out individually in the table by column from the original data

Comment: `{["Connector", "1"]=>4481, ["Connector", "10"]=>722, ["Connector", "2"]=>132, ["Connector", "3"]=>1467, ["Connector", "4"]=>3438, ["Connector", "5"]=>1627, ["Connector", "6"]=>508, ["EU Cords", "1"]=>218, ["EU Cords", "2"]=>100, ["US Cords", "1"]=>292, ["US Cords", "2"]=>256}`

that is the original data as it is supplied to the helper.  I need to peel The ,"#" portion as a column data, the "US Cords" etc. into a column, and then the =>"###" portion into a column on the table.

Comment: I am beginning to think I have to take what you gave me and then make that hash into an array.

Comment: Sure, sorry I took so long on this; I was out of town last weekend.

 `<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @table_data_two.each do |cda, cdb| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= cda %></td>
        <td><%= cdb %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>`